# Killing selenium server process programmatically in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, process

I am launching a selenium html suite on selenium server programatically via my own Eclipse plugin. Now this executes successfully and the browser is launched and begins running the suite. However should the 'intelligent' user decide to simply close the browser mid test, the selenium server process is left running in Eclipse. If it is left to run out, everything is fine and once the suite is finished the server is shutdown etc. However it would appear nothing is triggered in the process upon killing the browser process.

Now I know if i were doing this via command line I can simply ctrl+c and it triggers the shutdownhook and shuts the server down kindly. But I am unfortunately creating this process programatically via my Eclipse plugin and do not want the scenario of this plugin stuck thinking its still running when the test has in fact been closed.

Has anyone experienced this situation and found a means of resolving this? I am open to suggestions.

My thoughts are currently to run a seperate thread which constantly checks the state of selenium server, to see if it is infact idle...however I am yet to find information on where there is a way of checking the selenium server state?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

However, you could write `startup()` and `teardown()` methods for the Selenium suite which will start the server and shutdown the server instance after testing completion.

So you can use JUnit or TestNG and add these methods to invoke selserver start and selenium server shutdown.